# Hilt - Inject a list of Interface implementations

Tags: dagger-hilt

Let me show what I mean by code.

Interface:

```kotlin
interface MyInterface {
}
```

I have 2 implementation classes:

```kotlin
@Singleton
class Implementation1 @Inject constructor(
    private val gson: Gson,
) : MyInterface {
}
```

```kotlin
@Singleton
class Implementation2 @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
) : MyInterface {
}
```

I need a repository class with list of implementations of `MyInterface`:

```kotlin
@Singleton
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val implementations: List<MyInterface>,
) {
}
```

Problem part: I am trying to inject as below:

```kotlin
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object MyDiModule {
    @Provides
    fun providesImplementations(
        imp1: Implementation1,
        imp2: Implementation2,
    ): List<MyInterface> {
        return listOf(imp1, imp2)
    }
}
```

But I get compilation error:

```
/home/sayantan/AndroidStudioProjects/example/app/build/generated/hilt/component_sources/debug/com/example/ExampleApplication_HiltComponents.java:188: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.List<? extends com.example.MyInterface> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements FragmentGetContextFix.FragmentGetContextFixEntryPoint,
                         ^
```

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know how correct this answer is, but it works for me, so posting as answer.

This can be done using the annotation `@JvmSuppressWildcards`.

In the above example, everything is fine, I just need to add this annotation to the class where the dependencies are being injected, i.e. the `MyRepository` class.

```kotlin
@JvmSuppressWildcards
@Singleton
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val implementations: List<MyInterface>,
) {
}
```

Comment: it's better to put it before the type: `@JvmSuppressWildcards List<MyInterface>`

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same problem in the project I've been working on, but moving from List<> to Array<> seemed to fix it for me.

So in your case the hilt injection would look like:

```
@Provides
fun providesImplementations(
    imp1: Implementation1,
    imp2: Implementation2,
): Array<MyInterface> {
    return arrayOf(imp1, imp2)
}
```

Then used with:

```
@Singleton
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val implementations: Array<MyInterface>,
) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be late but would like to drop my thoughts.

Firstly, you need to annotate your `@Provides` methods in the module class because dagger would certainly throw an ***error of multiple bindings of `MyInterface`***.

For example:

```
enum class ImplType {
    Impl1, Impl2 
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ImplTypeAnnotation(val type: ImplType)

@Singleton
@Provides
@ImplTypeAnnotation(ImplType.Impl1)
fun provideImplementation1(impl1: Implementation1): MyInterface

// Do the same for Implementation2
```

Secondly, once these are done, you need to individually inject them into the **Repository** class. e.g.

```
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(
    @ImplTypeAnnotation(ImplType.Impl1) private val implementation1: MyInterface,
    @ImplTypeAnnotation(ImplType.Impl2) private val implementation2: MyInterface
) {
     // get the implementations as list here using Kotlin listOf()
}
```

**NB**: I'm not sure if providing `List<MyInterface>` would work.

Hope this helps!